# Unable to retrieve Story priority using versionone java sdk

Tags: versionone

I am trying to to get the Priority and Status of a Story item. I am trying the following but I am not getting any results. Note, I am successfully getting the Name and Description in the below code. Just priority and status are not returning any values.

```
IAssetType scopes = _metaModel.getAssetType("Story");

IAttributeDefinition NameAttribute = scopes.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
IAttributeDefinition DescriptionAttribute = scopes.getAttributeDefinition("Description");
IAttributeDefinition PriorityAttribute = scopes.getAttributeDefinition("Priority");
IAttributeDefinition StatusAttribute = scopes.getAttributeDefinition("Status");

Query query = new Query(scopes);

query.getSelection().add(NameAttribute);
query.getSelection().add(DescriptionAttribute);
query.getSelection().add(PriorityAttribute);
query.getSelection().add(StatusAttribute);

QueryResult result = _services.retrieve(query);
```

Thank you
Bhushan

Comment: Hey Bhushan, I saw your comment in our public openAgile HipChat room (http://www.hipchat.com/grNeYfSGw). Thanks for stopping in.
What happens when you try to get the same data, but just using a browser HTTP query, like this one:

https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Priority,Status

When I do that, (admin/admin for credentials) I get back correct data, so I'm curious what happens on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is [meta.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1):

```
<Server Base URI>/meta.v1/Scope?xsl=api.xsl
```

The results tells me the `Status` and `Priority` attributes are relationships. That means you would have to look them up in a follow-on query to get a meaningful value. You are probably better off using a [projection](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Attribute_Definition_Syntax#Projection) so you can get a text value. You probably want `Status.Name` and `Priority.Name` instead.

Although it does not affect the query itself, you have used the variable name `scopes`. Maybe you want to call the variable `stories` instead.